# dictionary[key] = value is it reference type?

Tags: c#, dictionary, data-structures

here nodes is a dictionary of `<string, List<string>>`
and childnodes is a `List<string>` and parentnode is a string.
Whenever I clear childnodes, the values for all the keys in the nodes get cleared.

```
    public void processData()
    {
        var hcols = Input.Columns.Take(Input.Columns.Count).ToList();
        var childNodes = new List<string>();
        var parentNode = "Default";

        for (var i= 1 ; i < hcols.Count -1 ; i++)
        {
            var splitString = hcols[i].Name.Split('_');

            if (nodes.ContainsKey(splitString[0]))
            {
                childNodes.Add(splitString[1]);
            }

            else
            {
                var childNodes2 = childNodes;
                if (!nodes.ContainsKey(splitString[0]) && childNodes.Count > 0)
                {
                    nodes[parentNode] = childNodes2;
                }
                nodes.Add(splitString[0], null);
                parentNode = splitString[0];
                childNodes.Clear();
                if (splitString.Length > 1) childNodes.Add(splitString[1]);
            }
            Array.Clear(splitString, 0, splitString.Length);
        }
        nodes[parentNode] = childNodes;
    }
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: You only ever create one `List<string>`. This object is a reference type. The same list is being added for every key. You need to create a separate list for each key, otherwise you'll get the behavior you've described.

Answer (score 1):

you are using the same list reference for all your keys. Instead of clearing the list, create a new one:

```
public void processData()
{
    var hcols = Input.Columns.Take(Input.Columns.Count).ToList();
    var childNodes = new List<string>();
    var parentNode = "Default";

    for (var i= 1 ; i < hcols.Count -1 ; i++)
    {
        var splitString = hcols[i].Name.Split('_');

        if (nodes.ContainsKey(splitString[0]))
        {
            childNodes.Add(splitString[1]);
        }

        else
        {
            var childNodes2 = new List<string>(childNodes); // depending on your case, you may want a copy here too
            if (!nodes.ContainsKey(splitString[0]) && childNodes.Count > 0)
            {
                nodes[parentNode] = childNodes2;
            }
            nodes.Add(splitString[0], null);
            parentNode = splitString[0];
            childNodes = new List<string>(); // instead of clear 
            if (splitString.Length > 1) childNodes.Add(splitString[1]);
        }
        Array.Clear(splitString, 0, splitString.Length);
    }
    nodes[parentNode] = childNodes;
}
```